# PHP: Store PHP variable in page to use in POST

Tags: php, post, get

Currently I put a constant on my webpage using PHP which I then send, with Ajax, to my POST function. However, this leaves it susceptible to hacking (the user could change the variable with Firebug), so is there a way to store the variable in the PHP of the page and then access it later on, in the POST method (or is the GET variable of the page still available in the POST function, since that's where I get the variable from)?

Comment: Sounds like `$_SESSION`...

Comment: If your variable is not changeable on the front end, there's no point passing it from there; just have it available in your script as a php variable. If this isn't what you mean, it might be worth rewording your question to be more specific.

Comment: there seems to be no need to store it in the browser anyways, so shy not declare it in the php script directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you have wanted is to store the post value to use it later.

Here you would need to use `$_SESSION`

You can do it like

```
session_start();
```

// Save variables into session

```
$_SESSION['thevalue'] = $_POST['value'];
```

Comment: I was thinking of that, I just wasn't sure if it's the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to store between successive calls from the same user use the follwing:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["your variable/constant"] = yourvaule;
```

Now use the variable as needed, accessing it as `$_SESSION["your variable/constant"]`

Hope it helps, and it's what you're asking.